# routing angularjs cannot get/

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Here is my home.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>here is home </h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

here my app.js:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ui.bootstrap'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})


.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
  })
  .state('app.home', {
    cache:false,
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/form-connection.html',
        controller: 'LoginConnect'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.registre', {
    url: '/registre',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/registre.html',
        controller: 'registreCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.facturer', {
    url: '/facturer',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/facturer.html',
        controller: 'facturerCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.params', {
    url: '/params',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/parametres.html',
        controller: 'parametresCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.documents', {
    url: '/documents',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/documents.html',
        controller: 'documentsCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

and here my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-csp.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-messages.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>



    <!-- your app's js -->

        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->


        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here the controller :

```
angular.module('starter', [])

.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})
.controller('registreCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})
.controller('facturerCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})
.controller('documentsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})
.controller('parametresCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})


.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
       delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
   }
])
//controller pour connection to API
.controller('LoginConnect', ['$scope', 'connecting','sendtoken',
function($scope,connecting,sendtoken){
    $scope.user = {};
    var users = $scope.user;
    $scope.connect = function (users) {
      var log = $scope.user.login;
      var pass = $scope.user.password;
      var mydata = {};
      connecting.login(log,pass).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        var montoken = result.data.token;
         sessionStorage.setItem('token',montoken);
         console.log(montoken);
      });


      var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
      console.log(mytoken);
       sendtoken.send(mytoken).then(function(userdata){
         $scope.datab = userdata;
       });
    };
  }
])

  //factory pour aller chercher le token
.factory('connecting', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q){
      var ConnectingFactory = {};
      ConnectingFactory.login = function(log,pass){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/login.php",
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
           transformRequest: function(obj) {
               var str = [];
               for(var p in obj)
               str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
               return str.join("&");
           },
           data: {login: log, password: pass}
           })
       .success(function(result){
          deferred.resolve(result);
          // var promise = deferred.promise;
          // promise.then(function(result){
          // var  mydata = result["data"];
          // console.log(mydata);
          //   }
          //);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
       };
       return ConnectingFactory;

}])
    //END factory pour aller chercher le token

    //Factory pour envoyer le token
    .factory('sendtoken', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q){
          var tokenreceipt = {};
          tokenreceipt.send = function(mytoken){
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/settings-get.php",
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
               transformRequest: function(obj) {
                   var str = [];
                   for(var p in obj)
                   str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                   return str.join("&");
               },
               data: {token : mytoken}
               })
               .success(function(userdata){
                  deferred.resolve(userdata);
                  // var promise = deferred.promise;
                  // promise.then(function(result){
                  // var  mydata = result["data"];
                  // console.log(mydata);
                  //   }
                  //);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
               };
               return tokenreceipt;
    }]);
      //END Factory pour envoyer le token


;













          //envoie du token

            // var deferredd = $q.defer();
            //
            // $http({
            //     method: 'POST',
            //     url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/settings-get.php",
            //     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            //     data: {token: $scope.user.token}
            //     })
            //     .success(function(mesdatas){
            //       deferredd.resolve(mesdatas);
            //         var promises = deferredd.promises;
            //         promises.then(function(mesdatas){
            //             $scope.datab = mesdatas;
            //               $scope.user.datab = mesdatas["data"];
            //        // jsonTab = angular.fromJson(result);
            //
            //
            //   });
            // })
            //   console.log($scope.user.token);

        //fin envoie token





//user connection

// End of user connection

// .controller('ButtonsCtrl', function ($scope) {
//   $scope.singleModel = 1;
//
//   $scope.radioModel = 'Middle';
//
//   $scope.checkModel = {
//     left: false,
//     middle: true,
//     right: false
//   };
//
//   $scope.checkResults = [];
//
//   $scope.$watchCollection('checkModel', function () {
//     $scope.checkResults = [];
//     angular.forEach($scope.checkModel, function (value, key) {
//       if (value) {
//         $scope.checkResults.push(key);
//       }
//     });
//   });
// })
```

My issue : i got nothing (white page ) when i go to url : http://localhost:8100/home
 i only have "Cannot GET /home" and nothing in the console

I'm new in angularJs someone can explain to me my issue ?

Comment: where is the controller?

Comment: i re-edit with the controller :)

Comment: What is it in your html template, that you expect to show in  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

Comment: I expect to see my h1 tag not a white page

Comment: Put an alert inside the homeCtrl, see if that is being hit. I can't seen anywhere in the view you are using the "homeCtrl"

Comment: No the alert didn t work too :(

Comment: i used this http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/

Comment: If the alert did not work, it means your homeCtrl is not being hit, and there is your problem. It cannot return the html so you are seeing a blank page. someone correct me if i am wrong

Comment: How are you running this? you call Home instead of index and index contains all script tags... you don't get 40* error that means you have access to the file in the server and the permissions are ok, but then it comes to my mind... are using a server? (sorry if it sounds dumb. I'm trying to get some context).
My best guess is that the page you are viewing is the default error page displayed by the server...

Answer (score 2):

You should be going to #/home:

```
http://localhost:8100/#/home
```

Comment: same white page even with this url

Answer (score 0):

Try the following url and sure your controller is loading:

```
http://localhost:8100/#/app/home
```

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your app.routing.module.ts, there might be a problem on path declaration.